# Temp Tables in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, temp-tables, ms-access-2013

Can we build Temp Tables for Queries in MS Access 2013?  Or does everything have to be done in nested queries.

For Example:

```
Select
FacilityID
,ActivityID
ClientID
Into
#Clients
From
Activities
```

Then
do something like

```
Select
FacilityID
,Count(ClientID) Over (partition By ActivityID) as ActivityCount
Into 
#Final
From
#Clients
```

This has been simplified- but you should have an idea.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is possible in Access if you run your queries from VBA code. You cannot use an action query like an Update or Make Table as a row source of another query so you have to build the source table first.

```vbs
Dim db as DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb()
db.Execute _
        "SELECT FacilityID, ActivityID, ClientID " & _
        "INTO Clients " & _
        "FROM Activities;", _
        dbFailOnError
db.execute _
        "SELECT FacilityID, ... " & _
        "INTO Final " & _
        "FROM Clients;", _
        dbFailOnError
```

(The `COUNT ... OVER (PARTITION BY ...)` code was removed to prevent the false impression that Access SQL supports that construct. It doesn't.)